# M SELECT INTO query isn't working

Tags: php, mysql

There is a minor problem in my query and I can't seem to figure it out. I am using `select into statement` to copy one table's column to another. The browser is showing error the following error:

> undeclared variable:new_tbl

When I open phpmyadmin, there is no `new_tbl` added to the particular database. Please tell me what's wrong with it. And the new-tbl does not already exists.

```
$sqli = "SELECT * INTO `new_tbl` FROM `order`";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sqli);
if($query) {
  echo "SELECT INTO query worked...";
} else {
  echo "ERROR:".mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Comment: 'Select INTO' -- does not create a table. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL does not support `select into`.  Use `create table as`:

```
create table new_tbl as
    SELECT * FROM `order`;
```

By the way `order` is a really bad name for a table because it is a SQL keyword.

Comment: and it's create table `new_tbl`.. you forgot that,,

Comment: yeah thats what im doing for past 3 minutes..it keeps showing dialogue box that you can accept answer after 5 minutes